# react native error :undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this._pressRow()')

Tags: android, react-native

some code:

```
renderMovie(product) {
   <TouchableHighlight
    onPress={this._pressRow()}>
   <View style={styles.container}>
     <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
       <Text style={styles.title}>{product.brand_domain}</Text>
       <Text style={styles.year}>{product.product_name}</Text>
     </View>
   </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
  }
  _pressRow(){
    this.props.navigator.push({
      title:'detail',
      component:DetailView
    })
   }
```

1.red screen and error log :undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this._pressRow()')
2.I use 'this._pressRow = this._pressRow.bind(this);' in constructor()
but its not work

3.doc example.but if I use 'onPress={this._onPressButton}' ,Click event no effect

```
renderButton: function() {
return (
  <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton}>
    <Image
     style={styles.button}
     source={require('image!myButton')}
   />
  </TouchableHighlight>
 );
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a scope problem here..

To fix it there are two possible solutions :

> 1. You need to bind `this` to the method :

```
<ListView
   dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
   renderRow={this.renderMovie.bind(this)}
/>
```

> 2. You can use ES6 fat arrows

```
renderMovie = (product) => {
  <TouchableHighlight
    onPress={this._pressRow()}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{product.brand_domain}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.year}>{product.product_name}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
}
```

and the `_pressRow` method :

```
_pressRow(){
  this.props.navigator.push({
    title:'detail',
    component:DetailView
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare your renderRow function in your ListView, you should bind this to the method:

```
<ListView
   dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
   renderRow={this.renderMovie.bind(this)}
/>
```